# flask_uploads: ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename'

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-uploads

I want to create a form that allows to send a picture with a description using flask forms.
I tried to use this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Exf8RbgKmhM

but I had troubles when launching app.py:

```
➜  website git:(master) ✗ python3.6 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'
```

I had to replace
`flask.ext.uploads` by `flask_uploads`
but now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_uploads.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug import secure_filename, FileStorage
ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename'
```

My imports and config looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, url_for, redirect, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, fields,TextField, StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField,validators
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length, DataRequired
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
```

I couldn't solve this issue, do you have any idea of what can I do ?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In `flask_uploads.py`

Change

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename,FileStorage
```

to

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage
```

Comment: Actually, don't do this, or you cannot update `Flask-Uploads` any more. See other answers for a better solution.

Answer (score 36):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-uploads/pull/28), it is a bug related to the current version 1.0.0 of workzeug. It's merged but not yet published in pypi.
The workaround know until now is to downgrade from `werkzeug=1.0.0` to `werkzeug==0.16.0`

So for do that you just need run the command:

```
pip install -U Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

Looking in the release notes from  werkzeug there is a version `0.16.1`, but in bug report there is no evidence that using that version could be of any help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did this:
Successfully uninstalled Werkzeug-1.0.0
Successfully installed Werkzeug-0.16.0
but I still get exactly the same error that ends with ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename'

Comment: Can u try to install this lib, see if it solves: `pip install Flask-Uploads`

Comment: It was already installed (it printed Requirement already satisfied).

Comment: Actually don't do this, or you will stick to a very old and outdated version of Werkzeug. Please see the other answers for a better solution.

Answer (score 24):

You are using a broken version of `Flask-Uploads`.

Unfortunately, the maintainer of the package decided not to release a new version of the package to PyPi.

You can use `Flask-Reuploaded` as a drop-in replacement, which fixes your problem.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/

Answer (score 9):

For Werkzeug version 2.1.2, just import `secure_filename` as:

`from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a

`-e git://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-uploads.git#egg=elasticutils`

in my `requirements.txt` file to get the latest version of flask-uploads from git.

Answer (score 0):

Use flask-Reuploaded rather than flask-uploads
it happens when you don't use werkzeug but still showing error so **THE SOLUTION IS--**
**pip install Flask-Reuploaded**