# problem with pipenv, flask-uploads, and Werkzeug

Tags: python, flask, pipenv, flask-uploads

I am working on a flask project. These are my dependencies in requirements.txt and it is working fine:

```
pytest==6.2.4
black==21.7b0
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.2.3
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
PyMySQL==1.0.2
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
flask-marshmallow==0.14.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.26.1
marshmallow


flask-uploads==0.2.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0


python-dotenv==0.19.0
flask-migrate==3.1.0
ldap3==2.9.1
psycopg2==2.9.1
```

The reason that I am using `Werkzeug==0.16.0` is explained in this post in StackOverflow:

[flask_uploads: ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628503/flask-uploads-importerror-cannot-import-name-secure-filename)

I am trying to use pipenv instead of venv.

So after creating the project and adding the pipfile to the project, I run this command:

```
pipenv install -r requirements.txt
```

But I get an error:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches werkzeug==0.16.0,>=0.14,>=2.0 (from -r C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv4r7ldp86requirements\pipenv-ajg0yy6e-constraints.txt (line 15))
Tried: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.2, 0.10.4, 0.10.4, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.11.
1, 0.11.2, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.11.3, 0.11.4, 0.11.4, 0.11.5, 0.11.5, 0.11.6, 0.11.6, 0.11.7, 0.11.7, 0.11.8, 0.11.8, 0.11.9, 0.11.9, 0.11.10, 0.11.10, 0.11.11, 0.11.11, 0.11.12, 0.11.12, 0.11.13, 0.11.13, 0.11.14, 0.11.14, 0.11.15, 0.11.
15, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.2, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.15.2, 0.15.3, 0.15.3, 0.15.4, 0.15.4, 0.15.5, 0.15.5, 0.15.6, 0.15.6, 0.16.0, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.1, 1.0
.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1
Skipped pre-versions: 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0rc5, 2.0.0rc5
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  werkzeug==0.16.0 (from -r C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv4r7ldp86requirements\pipenv-ajg0yy6e-constraints.txt (line 15))
  werkzeug>=0.14 (from flask-jwt-extended==4.2.3->-r C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv4r7ldp86requirements\pipenv-ajg0yy6e-constraints.txt (line 3))
  werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask==2.0.1->flask-migrate==3.1.0->-r C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv4r7ldp86requirements\pipenv-ajg0yy6e-constraints.txt (line 7))
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

> werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask==2.0.1->flask-migrate==3.1.0->-r C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv4r7ldp86requirements\pipenv-ajg0yy6e-constraints.txt (line 7))

This line means that to install flask-migrate 3.1.0, pipenv tried to install flask 2.0.1 (because [flask-migrate 3.1.0 needs Flask >= 0.9](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/blob/main/setup.cfg#L27)  so pipenv decided to install the latest Flask release) and this version of Flask requires werkzeug 2.0 at least.
And as you required Werkzeug 0.16.0, pipenv cant decide what to do.

**Solution**

**Edit**: As mentionned by Jürgen Gmach, using flask-reuploaded in place of flask-uploads might be a good way to go (Jürgen Gmach being the maintainer of flask-reuploaded)

The bug you are referencing from flask-upload has been fixed on the github repository but not released on pypi. They were no release on pypi since 2016, I bet they won't do it (Maybe you can ask for it on the github page).

- Install the latest code from flask-uploads from github
- You may give a try on installing Werkzeug 2.0.1
- Stop using this flask module and find an other way of doing what it does. -> flask-reuploaded

You can install code from github in a `requirement.txt`. For reference: [How to state in requirements.txt a direct github source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source)

Comment: There is a successor to Flask-Uploads, see https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded

Answer (score 0):

You should use Flask-Uploads' successor, https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded

It is not only well maintained, compatible with current versions of werkzeug, but it also fixed a security issue with Flask-Uploads